# What's the meaning of "legal system" in the context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, interpretation

In some countries people have no faith in the **legal system**.

I interpreted it —  In some countries people don't have faith  in how the law of that country works./how the law is organized.

Am i correct as to my interpretation of the sentence?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.